# Mod_Rewrite Question

Tags: mod-rewrite

How can I turn the following URL example 1 to example 2 using mod_rewrite?

Example 1

```
http://www.example.com/cat/index.php?cat=fruit&sub1=apple&sub2=green
```

Example 2

```
http://www.example.com/cat/fruit/apple/green/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?$1=$2&sub1=$3&sub2=$4 [NC]
```

`$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4` represent the four matched groups `(.*)`

If there is a variable number of subcategories, you should change your strategy:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?$1=$2&subcat_string=$3 [NC]
```

And parse the `subcat_string` manually (example in python):

```
# subcat_string will be something like "apple/green"
subcats = subcat_string.split("/")
# subcats is now ["apple", "green"]
```